# Docker no mapea los cambios hechos en React?

Tags: reactjs, docker

He creado una aplicación en reactjs y la he montado en docker, pero a la hora de hacer cambios en la carpeta de desarrollo no se actualiza en la imagen de Docker.

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:14.15.4-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY  package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  client:
    stdin_open: true
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes: 
      - './:/app:'
    tty: true
```

cuando lo despliego funciona bien a la hora de realizar un cambio para que se muestren tengo que reiniciar el container para que coja los cambios.

Sugerencias por favor.

Comment: Faltaría ver qué hace el script `npm start`.

Comment: es react 17.0.1 "start": "react-scripts start",

Comment: Es normal. React funciona con un eventloop. Cuando arranca por primera vez se carga la app en memoria y rmpeiza a gestionarse el bucle de eventos. Si cambias algo no de verá afectado porque la app ya está arrancada. La solución es o reiniciar el docker o añadir librerías en tu app que detecten que de ha hecho un cambio y que se reinicie la app

Answer (score 1):

Veo dos problemas:

Puede que no te funcione porque montas el directorio local en `/app:`, con dos puntos al final, supongo que es un fallo tipográfico. Como no es el directorio donde se ejecuta la aplicación, no detecta los cambios. Al reconstruir el contenedor, vuelves a copias el directorio local en `/app` con lo que ya ves los cambios. Bastaría con quitar esos dos puntos `:`.

Otro problema más sutil que vas a tener es que los módulos que se instalan en el directorio `/app/node_modules` del contenedor se solapan con los del directorio local al montar el volumen `'./:/app'`. Podría ser que algún binario sea distinto y sea origen de problemas. Para evitarlo, añade el directorio como volumen *anónimo* en el `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
    volumes: 
      - './:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
```