# Docker no mapea los cambios hechos en React usando volumenes?

Tags: reactjs, docker

```
#Dockerfile
FROM node:14.15.4-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY  package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]

#docker-compose
version: "3.8"
services: 
  client:
    stdin_open: true
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes: 
      - './:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    tty: true
```

Apliqué lo que muestra acá: [Docker no mapea los cambios hechos en React?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/419747/docker-no-mapea-los-cambios-hechos-en-react) pero no tuve resultados. Incluso probé en eliminar la carpeta `node_modules` y nada.